# 100% Body Height w/ Twitter Bootstrap & Fixed Navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap with a fixed navbar, so I have the following HAML & CSS:

HAML

```
%html
  %body
    %header
      .navbar
        ...
    #main-wrapper
      .container
    %footer
```

CSS

```
body { 
  padding-top: 60px 
  height: 100%;
}
```

The issue is that this create a body 60px larger than the page height, so I always have a scroll bar on the pages, even when it's not needed to display the content.  I NEED the 60px of padding though in order for the responsive behavior to work correctly.

Is there any way to keep this padding and still achieve a body height of exactly 100%?

Comment: Don't use the height:100%. You don't need to. Take the bootstrap approach in his home web page http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ (inspect the body with a development tool). The body will response to the responsive web desing that you require if you active ths .css for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<body>
  <div style='height: 100%; background:blue;'>
    <div style='height: 60px; background:red;'>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Let the enclosing div have a height of 100%, and add some internal element to create the padding.